vsphere_virtual_machine will be updated in-place : how to add ignore_changes in terragrunt?
After a virtual machine is created using the provider, after running an apply again terragrunt apply wants to update the virtual-machine in-place as the fields ept_rvi_mode and hv_mode are constantly being changed even without touching those fields.
ACcording to terraform github: It looks like that the provider is using one of automatic, on or off, where VSphere unsets the field to an empty string "".
How can I add  a work-around in resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" ?
lifecycle {
  ignore_changes = [
    ept_rvi_mode,
    hv_mode
  ]
}

Step to reproduce : Run a terragrunt apply immediately followed by a new run of terragrunt apply
My configuration
Terragrunt.hcl in root:
inputs = {
  vmrp                   = "my_cluster/Resources"
  dc                     = "dc1"
  datastore_cluster      = "my_cluster"
  domain                 = "test.local"
  dns_suffix_list        = ["test.local"]
  join_domain            = true
  windomain              = "test.local"
  domain_admin_user      = "${get_env("vsphere_user")}"
  domain_admin_password  = "${get_env("vsphere_pwd")}"
}

generate "config" {
  path      = "config.hcl"
  if_exists = "overwrite"
  contents  = <<EOF
locals {
  env        = "xxx"
}
EOF
}

generate "backend" {
  path      = "backend.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket  = "${get_env("cloud_bucket")}"
    prefix  = "terraform/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    credentials = "${get_env("cloud_confg")}"
  }
}
EOF
}

generate "provider" {
  path      = "provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "${get_env("vsphere_user")}"
  password       = "${get_env("vsphere_pwd")}"
  vsphere_server = "192.x.x.x."

  # if you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}
EOF

}

And my terragrunt.hcl in a specific folder (my vm name)
include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

locals {
  config = read_terragrunt_config(find_in_parent_folders("config.hcl"))
}

terraform {
  source = "tfr:///Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere//.?version=3.5.0"
}

inputs = {
  vmtemp                 = "TPL-UBUNTU"
  instances              = 1
  cpu_number             = 2
  ram_size               = 4096
  cpu_hot_add_enabled    = true
  cpu_hot_remove_enabled = true
  memory_hot_add_enabled = true
  vmnameformat           = "%02d" #To use three decimal with leading zero vmnames will be AdvancedVM01,AdvancedVM02
  vmname                 = "${local.config.locals.envshort}-${basename(get_terragrunt_dir())}-"
  vmfolder               = "FR"
  is_windows_image       = false
  dns_server_list        = ["192.168.2.7"]
  vmgateway              = "192.168.2.254"
  disk_size_gb           = [50]

  network = {
    mynetwork= [""] # To use DHCP create Empty list ["192.168.2.134",""]; You can also use a CIDR annotation;
  }
}

my config_hcl
locals {
  env = "testing"
}


the fields ept_rvi_mode and hv_mode are constantly being changed even without touching those fields - have you considered setting these values, for example using the default values?

@RuiJarimba I already tried to set those fields in terragrunt.hcl but it didn't work :'(. I need to find a way to ignore those fields .. But I don't know how
